# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello Following is my query, but I get error while run it:

```
$out_let_product = OutLet::where('id', Redis::get('out_let_id') )->with(
    ['products' => function($query){
        $query->with(['prices', 'combinations' => function($query){
            $query->where('prices.active', '=', '1');                
        }]);
    }])->get();
```

In above code 'prices' and 'combinations' = function in product model. and it's working perfectly but the problem is when I include " $query->where('prices.active', '=', '1'); " this line inside, system raised error like below:

"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'prices.active' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `product_combinations` where `product_combinations`.`product_id` in (1, 2, 3) and `prices`.`active` = 1 and `product_combinations`.`deleted_at` is null)",

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `combinations` and `prices` refer to different tables and you are using `price.active` in the `combinations`. Try using this,

```
$out_let_product = OutLet::where('id', Redis::get('out_let_id') )->with(
    ['products' => function($query){
        $query->with(['combinations' => function($query){
            $query->select('combinations.*', 'prices.*')
                  ->join('prices', function($join) {
                      $join->on('prices.id' '=', 'combination.id') // or your join logic
                           ->where('prices.active', '=', 1)                    
                  })->where(// where clause for combination);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: I've already done that though, but I need to run two where clause at same position, like $query->where('prices.active', '=', '1');     I want to run another where clause for 'combinations' as well.

Comment: Why don't you try `join` between `prices` and `combinations` instead of using `with`. That way it will be less complex.

Comment: I edited my answer. I tried giving you a brief idea of what I was trying to say. I hope I could explain.

Comment: I think I couldn't explain the things correctly, "combinations" and "prices" are the relation with "products", more clearly each product has "combinations" and  "prices", so I want those related data. Ex. for product id: 1 I want data associated with "combinations" and "prices".

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, yes I got my solutions:

```
$out_let_product = OutLet::where('id', Redis::get('out_let_id') )->with(
    ['products' => function($query){
        $query->with(['prices' => function($query){
            $query->where('product_prices.active', '=', '1'); //product_prices is DB: Table name

        }]);
        $query->with(['combinations' => function($query){
            query->where('product_combinations.id', '1');  //product_combinations is DB: Table name
        }]);
    }])->get();
```